# Montecarlo and rstudio error: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)

Tags: r, rstudio, montecarlo

This will be difficult to replicate because I am using R's Monte Carlo package to call a Fortran subroutine within RStudio and I am not including the subroutine here because it is complicated. In any case, my code below fails before entering that subroutine (I think). Here is the code:

```
#####Monte Carlo
rsentTinitial=10
rTinitial=15
res_presets = character(0)
res_presets[1] = 'win' 
res_presets2 = eval(parse(text = "res_presets[1]", encoding = "UTF-8"))
noquote(res_presets2)
ntimestep<-c(264)
mySENSRange2 <- function(irflag,rricomp,rrrandom,res_presets2,rtairsent2, rtairback2, irrtimestep) {
  if (!is.loaded('rwrapper')) {
      dyn.load("rwrapper.so")
  }
  retvals <- .Fortran("RSENSRANGE",irflag = as.integer(irflag), icomp = as.integer(rricomp),
                      rCOUPLEVAR = as.numeric(rrrandom), noquote(res_presets2), rtairsent2 = as.array(rtairsent2[1:ntimestep]),
                      rtairback2 = as.array(rtairback2[1:ntimestep]),irrtimestep = as.integer(irrtimestep))
  rmonteresult<-return(list("sentTemps"=retvals$rtairsent2,"CalcTemps"=retvals$rtairback2, "Timesteps"=retvals$irrtimestep))
}
library(MonteCarlo)
irflag_grid<-c(1)
rricomp_grid<-c(1) #Hardwiring for now
rrrandom_grid<-seq(1,2,0.2)
res_presets2_grid<-c(noquote(res_presets2))
rtairsent_grid<-c(data.frame(matrix(1: ntimestep),rsentTinitial))
names(rtairsent_grid)<-c("Timestep","AirTemp")
rtairback_grid<-c(data.frame(matrix(1:ntimestep),rTinitial))
names(rtairback_grid)<-c("Timestep","AirTemp")
irrtimestep_grid<-c(ntimestep)

param_list=list("irflag"=irflag_grid, "rricomp"=rricomp_grid, "rrrandom"=rrrandom_grid,"res_presets2"=as.character(noquote(res_presets2_grid)),
                "rtairsent2"=rtairsent_grid$AirTemp[1:ntimestep],"rtairback2"=rtairback_grid$AirTemp[1:ntimestep],"irrtimestep"=irrtimestep_grid)
monteResult<-MonteCarlo(func=mySENSRange2, nrep=20, param_list=param_list, ncpus=1)
df<-MakeFrame(list(CalcTemps,sentTemps,Timesteps))
```

and here are the errors:

```
Error in func(irflag = param_list[[1]][1], rricomp = param_list[[2]][1],  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
```

And also from the last line of the code (the Makeframe line) I get this:

```
Error in MakeFrame(list(CalcTemps, sentTemps, Timesteps)) : 
  object 'CalcTemps' not found
```

For the first error it appears that I may have a NaN or that I may be dividing by zero somewhere but I simply can not see that. Any suggestions of what may be going wrong will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with rstudio?  That is the IDE and I don't see anything that indicates an IDE problem.   What do you get if you type `rtairsent_grid$AirTemp[1:ntimestep]`  in the console?

Comment: @Elin: Thank you for your kind reply. I am not sure what do you mean by IDE (I am a beginner with rstudio). When I type the above I get 264 times 10 (as many 10s as the ntimestep value is).

Comment: IDE means integrated development environment.  It's nothing to do with your code, it's just a place to type and run your code.    Do you mean you get `2640` or that you get the expression `264*10`?

Comment: @Elin: I am getting this: > rtairsent_grid$AirTemp[1:ntimestep]
  [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 [40] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 [79] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
...cutting the rest down due to length

Answer (score 1):

I will briefly answer my question in case it is useful to someone.

The MakeFrame error above was solved with:

```
df<-MakeFrame(monteResult)
```

The  NA/NaN/Inf  error was because the Monte Carlo package takes scalar inputs and not arrays. So I just send a scalar to my function and within my function I used a 3rd variable to prepare an array for my function to call after the fortran subroutine. The code is a bit long so I keep this clean I will not upload it (but happy to send it to anyone).